# Как заставить GravitySnapHelper докручивать элементы в горизонтальном recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Использую GravitySnapHelper в RecyclerView с горизонтальной прокруткой.
Использую `app:snapGravity="start"`. Элементы прокручиваются, всё работает. Ширина элемента (itemView) в горизонтальном recyclerview составляет 80% от ширины экрана, при этом в 20% оставшихся показывается уже следующий элемент списка (itemView):

Скриншот:

[image: описание]

Не знаю как сформулировать вопрос правильно. Нужно как-то более по-человечески прокручиваться к следующим элементам при свайпе. Так как на данный момент, чтобы прокрутиться, необходимо делать свайп пальцем, хватая чуть ли не за середину элемента, иначе элементы не прокрутятся а вернутся обратно к своему местоположению, откуда я их "свайпал/хватал".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам столкнулся с такой задачей.

Что могу вам посоветовать? Либо использовать

```
val snapHelper: SnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
```

Он скроллит страницы как `ViewPager`. Там правда может быть косяк с тем, чтоб оно прилипало к краю экрана. Тут надо либо самому править SnapHelper либо можно заюзать либо [GravityPagerSnapHelper](https://github.com/rubensousa/GravitySnapHelper/blob/master/gravitysnaphelper/src/main/java/com/github/rubensousa/gravitysnaphelper/GravityPagerSnapHelper.java).

Comment: Попробывал `GravityPagerSnapHelper` . Листать стало более удобно. Но пролистывает теперь только по 1 элементу за свайп теперь не зависит от того, как быстро и сильнее мы свайпнули. При использовании `GravitySnapHelper` можно было пролистывать большее кол-во элементов, да и настройка была в xml: `app:snapMaxFlingSizeFraction="3"` которой можно установить кол-во прокручиваемых элементов. Как здесь настроить это поведение - не ясно. Если здесь можно это как-то прикрутить, то я приму с радостью этот ответ, так как он помог собственно решить основную проблему.

Comment: Ну тогда вам придется скорее всего либо что-то своё писать, либо пользоваться GravitySnapHelper. Потому что PageSnapHelper сам по себе как раз и подразумевает не больше одной страницы за раз